Simplest, cheapest force/pressure sensor to be used as a human interface?
I am a beginner in engineering looking for a pretty precise force sensor that can withhold and measure pressures up to the maximum force a human could exert on it with their arm. What kind of pressure sensor should I use? Should I buy strain gauges or load cells, or is there a long-lasting variable resistor that can be made out of common materials? Honestly, I am looking for any solution to the problem of measuring the exact force someone is exerting against a solid surface - I just assume pressure sensors would be best. If there's a cheaper or more obvious option like recording muscle activity, please let me know. Any help would be appreciated.

look at bathroom scales

Theres the spring scale. No electronics needed!

@jsotola Thank you for the suggestion! I actually had looked into load cells and some other common mechanisms used for weight measurement, but they seem very lacking in responsiveness - And some may not work when going against gravity? That's why I am at a loss here.
